# filebeat module output configuration should be configurable in modules.d/<module.yml>?

Tags: filebeat

I am new to filebeat and I am not able to find module specific output configuration
There are several modules supported by filebeat

```
root@10.60.51.230#ls /etc/filebeat/modules.d/

activemq.yml.disabled     cyberarkpas.yml.disabled       infoblox.yml.disabled   
..
netscout.yml.disabled         radware.yml.disabled     zeek.yml.disabled
..
o365.yml.bak                  santa.yml.disabled       zoom.yml.disabled
...
```

The output of each module is specified by the following configuration in filebeat.yml:
root@10.60.51.230#grep -B2 -A20 -i output filebeat.yml

```
# -------------------------------- File Output ---------------------------------
output.file:
  # Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
  enabled: true

  # Configure JSON encoding
  codec.json:
    # Pretty-print JSON event
    pretty: true

    # Configure escaping HTML symbols in strings.
    #escape_html: false

  # Path to the directory where to save the generated files. The option is
  # mandatory.
  **path: "/var/module_o365/azure_ad"**
```

So if there are multiple modules actively running and fetching data, every module (aka beat) output is stored in /var/module_o365/azure_ad ?
In other words, why is this a global setting?  should it be not a setting within module.yml ?
Etc
Movint the output section to a specific module ( say, o365.yml) does not seem to work